# RunCloud Deployment Script vs Laravel Forge - why git merge instead of git pull?

Tags: git, laravel

**Laravel Forge** deployment script is obvious for me:

```
cd /home/forge/foo.bar
git pull origin develop
```

It pulls from the branch and deploys the rest.

However **RunCloud** says something different:

> You **don't have to** run git fetch command but **you must include** your own
>   git merge command.

Why `git merge`? Why I must? What does this mean?

Why I can't do the same as with Forge?

Can I get any human explanation?

Comment: This is apples to oranges to me.  I don't follow the comparison.

Comment: It's not a question about which one is better - it's a question about why the approach is different - `git merge` vs `git pull origin develop`…

Answer (score 0):

Considering `git pull` is `git fetch` + `git merge`, it is probable that RunCloud does the fetch for you.

All you need is to do the merge part of the pull in order to complete it.

You can see an example in the RunCloud blog post "[Laravel With GIT Deployment The Right Way](https://blog.runcloud.io/2017/01/15/laravel-with-git-deployment-the-right-way.html)"

Check out the [Git part of the runcloud doc](https://runcloud.io/docs/server/web-application.html#git):

> One of the best features of RunCloud is that you can use GIT to attach your project to your Web Application. You can do an automatic pull to sync your website with your code.

So the fetch is done for you.